# Finding a Lower Bound for the Lalescu Expression $\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!} - \sqrt[n]{n!\vphantom{(n+1)!}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

It would appear that $(n/(n+1))^{n+1}$ is a lower bound for the Lalescu expression $\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!} - \sqrt[n]{n!\vphantom{(n+1)!}}$ (I have an upper bound of $(n/(n+1))^{n}$ already, and both bounds tend towards $1/e$ for large $n$, which of course is Lalescu's limit).

My question is : How would one derive algebraically this lower bound of $(n/(n+1))^{n+1}$ ?

Comment: Since $\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!} - \sqrt[n]{n!\vphantom{(n+1)!}}$ is decreasing and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!} - \sqrt[n]{n!\vphantom{(n+1)!}}=\frac1e$, so $\{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!} - \sqrt[n]{n!\vphantom{(n+1)!}}\}$ has the lowebound $\frac1e$.

Comment: That does not answer the question at all. The question is how to derive this lower bound so that the Sandwich Theorem could be used to actually give the limit - the post assumes knowledge of the limit to engineer a lower bound.

Comment: what do you mean by "algebraically"?

Comment: By using algebra, that's all. Maybe just ignore the word "algebraically" !

Comment: Perhaps there is a different lower bound that exists? Any suggestions/help would be appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a non-trivial question - much harder than I imagined.

Comment: I do not think it is decresing. Do you have a proof of that xpaul?